# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following javascript code:

```
 var table = "<tr>" +
    "<td style='width:48%' class='ads-details-td'><div>" +
    "<p><strong> <a href='#' onclick='showServiceInfo(" + data.services[i].service_name + ")'"+ data.services[i].service_name + "</a> </strong></p>" +
    "</div></td>" +
    "<td style='width:16%' class='price-td'><div><strong> <input type='number' min='1' value='1' id='serviceQuantity"+data.services[i].service_identification+"' onchange='computePrice("+ data.services[i].service_identification+")' ></strong></div></td>" +
     "<td style='width:16%' class='price-td'><div><strong><p id='servicePrice"+data.services[i].service_identification+"'>"+data.services[i].service_price+"</p> </div></td>" +
      "<td style='width:10%' class='action-td'><div>" + 
        "<p> <a class='btn btn-primary'> <i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i> Add </a></p>" +
        "</div></td>"
```

and my javascript function is

```
function showServiceInfo(x)
{
    alert(x)
    console.log(x)
}
```

Here

```
data.services[i].service_name
```

is a variable I am fetching from ajax request.
I am unable to understand what i missed or added extra `)`

Comment: add up a jsfiddle of your question for better understanding.

Comment: You're also missing the closing `</tr>` tag

Answer (score 2):

You are not missing a `)`, however, you are missing the `>` for the link. You are also missing quotes around the variable being put into the function, and if the value `data.services[i].service_name` is a string that is not the name of an variable, this will also cause an error because that variable is undefined.

```
"<a href='#' onclick='showServiceInfo(" + data.services[i].service_name + ")'"+ data.services[i].service_name + "</a>"
```

should be

```
"<a href='#' onclick='showServiceInfo(\"" + data.services[i].service_name + "\")'>"+ data.services[i].service_name + "</a>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I add your code but still getting same error.

Comment: Yea, I thought it might be something else. That's why I hesitated to close-vote for typographical error and actually test what I wrote. All I got was that without the closing bracket, the table is malformed and the link isn't even visible, but no console errors. With the bracket, I get an error about the variable not being defined. Will be editing with a fix for that. But I don't get the same error as you.

Comment: I changed the value of  data.services[i].service_name. I create a variable and assign value to it and pass it to the function. It's working perfect but whenever I tried to pass value from  JSON response i am getting same error.

Comment: All I can suggest at the moment is to create a jsfiddle as suggested earlier